# How to download a file from gmplib.org?

Tags: installation, 10.04

I am new to Ubuntu and am trying to open a link in a website. The link can be opened in Windows but not in Ubuntu Lucid. Is there any restriction in Ubuntu for opening a link that may have codes and packages to install? This is the link of the site: http://gmplib.org/ and I need to click on "download benchmark sources".

Thanks.

Also asked here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2123075

Comment: I clicked on [download benchmark sources](ftp://ftp.gmplib.org/pub/misc/gmpbench-0.2.tar.bz2) and got a 19.5 KiB file (.tar.bz2) downloaded. I don't there's ever been "any restriction in ubuntu for opening a link that may have codes and packages to install".

Answer (score 0):

No file downloads fine for me.

Assume you mean the link ftp://ftp.gmplib.org/pub/misc/gmpbench-0.2.tar.bz2

Which you can see is an FTP site.

Also try the wget command

```
wget ftp://ftp.gmplib.org/pub/misc/gmpbench-0.2.tar.bz2
```

You might need to install the command

```
sudo apt-get install wget
```

Comment: I tried the link in windows and it is working but in my ubuntu lucid I just get time out error as it is not able to open the link

Comment: I think there is a restriction in my system. I tried to change the repositories to allow opening the site but still got problem. How I can allow codes in my software services?

Comment: Check my post for another alternative command for retrieving file

Comment: using the first one I get the same error and the process will stay in a loop of trying and getting nothing from the site. 
I used the second code and it says every thing is up to date and nothing changed.

Comment: Have you setup a firewall and prevented port 21 from being accessable?